# How do absolute paths get into the `NEEDED` portion of the dynamic section of an executable?

Tags: linux, makefile, elf, readelf

I have a number of executables which link against a single lib path. For instance, the executable `foo` links against (say) `libboost_system.so` and `libfoo.so`, the latter of which I build myself. I place third party libraries in a variable `LDLIBS`, and link my library via `-lfoo`, so that the makefile line looks as follows:

```
foo: objects
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS) -lfoo
```

However, when I `readelf`, I see my own path!

```
$ readelf --dynamic foo 

Dynamic section at offset 0x3c68 contains 48 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [/home/username/foo_dir/lib/libfoo.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_system.so.1.58.0]
```

My own library is the only library which has an absolute path in it.

How can I get rid of this monstrosity using only the makefile, i.e., without using `patchelf --replace-needed` or `chrpath`?

Comment: Did you add `-L/home/nthompson/foo_dir/lib/` when linking?

Comment: Yes; it links just fine.

Comment: If there is no absolute path, where do you expect the dynamic loader to find it?

Comment: Using the `ORIGIN` variable in the executable.